# Simple phone masking in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a jQuery plugin for a phone mask on a textfield (ie. xxx-xxx-xxxx). It should be pretty simple - just inserting hyphens into the appropriate places when a user types. For various reasons, I can't use plugins. It has to be from scratch. The only real plugin I've found is a little too expansive for my purposes. I'm currently doing something like this:

```
var number = phoneTextbox.val().replace(/\D/g, '');

var output = "";
for (var i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    if (i == 2) {
        output += number[i] + '-';
    } else if (i == 5) {
        output += number[i] + '-';
    } else {
        output += number[i];
    }
}
phoneTextbox.val(output);
```

But it gets wonky when trying to edit or delete numbers. Any simpler solutions out there that just handle a use case as simple as mine?

EDIT: I suppose my 'masking' terminology has confused some. By masking, I mean the functionality that this plugin accomplishes: http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ - which is what I'd be using if it was permitted!

Comment: What browser's do you have to support? HTML5 added the `placeholder` attribute that does exactly this. I think it's supported in all the modern browsers and IE since version 10. For more information see [caniuse.com/...](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder)

Comment: In my opinion, you shouldn't over engineer this. Have three inputs structured (`<input>`) `<input>` - `<input>`, auto focus the next input when the previous one is full, and have them typed as password so they only show ***.

Comment: I've been given my requirements and have to stick to them, unfortunately! As is tradition in the dev world. Single input box. Placeholders won't cut it, either.

Comment: Are you asking how to format a string or how to handle keypresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function formatPhone(p){
   if (p.length !== 10){
       console.warn("Invalid phone length");
       return p;
   }
   return [p.substr(0,3), p.substr(3,3), p.substr(6,4)].join("-");
}
```

Here is a fiddle showing how it might be used: http://jsfiddle.net/692ckv12/

Comment: This essentially covered my bases, with some tweaking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/50wyoqyt/)***

Just use the built in constructs for masking and some simple javascript for focus.

html

```
<div>
 <div>Phone Number</div>
 <div class="phone">
    ( <input type="password" maxlength="3" width="10px" /> ) <input type="password" maxlength=3 /> - <input type="password" maxlength=4 />
 </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.phone input{
 padding:1px;
 width: 15px;
 text-align:center;
}
.phone input:last-child{
 width: 20px;
}
```

js

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.phone input');
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
 var input = inputs[i];
 (function(copy){
  input.oninput = function(){
   if(this.value.length == this.getAttribute("maxlength")){
    inputs[copy+1].focus();      
   }
  };
 })(i);
}
```

Comment: Single textbox, unfortunately. (And why have several people suggested that these be password fields?)

Answer (score -1):

There are already plugins out there which allow for masking input fields; no need to reinvent the wheel. Take a look at [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/), for example (or just google for "jquery mask input").

Comment: Per the OP: _"For various reasons, I can't use plugins. It has to be from scratch..."_